# ¿Por que live server de visual studio code me muestra los archivos de mi carpeta pero al momento de presionar alguno me lo descarga?

Tags: studio, visual

Ya desinstale la extension, el visual por completo pero el problema persiste y no se que mas intentar no avanza de este punto por favor alguiem que resuelva este problema, gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que estás hablando de vscode-live-server. Este, de forma natural, sólo funciona para "servir los archivos del frontend", no es un webserver que compile/ejecute PHP u otros lenguajes del Backend.

Sin embargo es posible que agregándole al vscode-live-server las webextensión pueda ejecutar/compilar PHP
https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/HEAD/docs/faqs.md#how-to-use-live-server-web-extension

Otra opción es o bien utilizar un webserver configurado para PHP (como apache, nginx, etc; configuración de virtual host y demás) o más simple, usar el propio webserver interno de php.

Para esto último, desde una terminal y posicionado en tu carpeta de trabajo, ejecutas
`~/proyecto_php$ php -S localhost:8000`
con esto tendrás disponible tu aplicación php en localhost:8000/
Acá tienes más info sobre esto https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.webserver.php